# winpcap silent install

Tags: installation, winpcap

I'm doing an installation setup now. I want to install winpcap.exe silently. Are there any switches for doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silent install was removed due to misuse. You basically have three options:

- Install it without silent installer
- Use a third party installer that does allow silent install (the [Nmap installer](http://nmap.org/download.html#windows) allows you to install WinPCap silently)
- Do the installation manually
- Get WinPcap Pro, the installer for this allows silent install.